# Highcharts - is it possible to apply opacity for a specific zone?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, opacity

I need to apply opacity to specific parts of spline and bars (like zones) in Highcharts. 
Do you think it is doable?

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: [-10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 10, 10, 5, 0, -5],
        opacity: 0.3, // Works here, for the whole line
        zones: [{
            value: 0,
            color: '#f7a35c',
            opacity: 0.3 // Not applicable here, for specific zone
        }, {
            value: 10,
            color: '#7cb5ec'
        }, {
            color: '#90ed7d'
        }]
    }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ofudq29r/

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `color` property as an RGBA value, where the last parameter is an opacity.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5zobaLes/

```
{
     value: 0,
     color: 'rgba(193, 66, 66, 0.3)',
},
```